# VBA: Array/Ubound sometimes working - not always returning full array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I previously had a question answered for something unrelated (looping) and the recommendation included using arrays & Ubounds which all worked great at first (see my accepting the answer) but now the array portion isn't returning a full array ALL the time when activating or calling this sub.

**Background**

I have a worksheet(s) where 2 columns Range("D7:E28") contain user input/selections that are then sent to a hidden "Lookup" ws where a table is located for a cross ref/match. The resulting lookup results are then sent to a "Summary List" ws and listed one after the other.

*Link: [VBA: Worksheet loop only staying on the active sheet instead of looping through all specified worksheets in the workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75837468/vba-worksheet-loop-only-staying-on-the-active-sheet-instead-of-looping-through)*

Code:

```
Sub WS_Lookup()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LookupWS As Worksheet
    Dim SummaryCodeWS As Worksheet
    Dim lookupLR As Long
    Dim summaryRow As Range
    Dim arr As Variant
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set LookupWS = wb.Worksheets("Lookup")
    Set SummaryCodeWS = wb.Worksheets("Summary List")
    lookupLR = LookupWS.Range("K10000").End(xlUp).Row
                
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible And ws.Name <> " " Then
                    
            Set summaryRow = SummaryCodeWS.Range("B10000").End(xlUp).Offset(2).EntireRow
            summaryRow.Columns("A").Value = ws.Range("A4").Value
                    
            LookupWS.Range("G3:H24").Value = ws.Range("D7:E28").Value
                    
            arr = LookupWS.Range("K4:O" & lookupLR).Value
            summaryRow.Columns("B").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr 
                                  
            With summaryRow.Range("A1:F1").Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                 .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                 .Weight = xlThin
                 .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            End With
            
         End If
    Next ws
    
    With SummaryCodeWS
        .Visible = xlSheetVisible
        .Move After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    End With
    
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    
End Sub
```

When trying to troubleshoot, I would add/remove values from the user selections and I can get it to reset sometimes and show a full "new" summary but when playing it again (unchanged user selections), it will shorten the array to the first or sometimes up to the 2nd value only. I have attached a screenshot to explain the varying array size.

I was playing around with the ubound arguments just to understand it more but it's out of my depth at this point.  I haven't changed anything with the syntax as it appears consistent with other upvoted resolutions here.

I hope this makes sense and would appreciate any help!

[image: WB screenshot]

Comment: What does `Debug.Print lookupLR` return? Should you be finding the last row inside the loop?

Comment: It returns the number 4.

Comment: Is that what you expect? Seems like not.

Comment: Sorry clicked enter without answering your full question. But the ubound/array is new for me and this is my original code that prompted it:                                                 
                                                                                  
 'Master lookup obt ea. term & code type for lookup
   lookupWS.Range("G3:H24").Value = ws.Range("D7:E28").Value 
        
 'Copy/paste LU table into summary ws
 lookupWS.Range("K4:O" & lookupLR).Copy
 SummaryCodeWS.Range("B" & summaryLR).Offset(2, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: 'Master lookup obt ea. term & code type for lookup lookupWS.Range("G3:H24").Value = ws.Range("D7:E28").Value

Comment: 'Then copy/paste LU table into summary ws lookupWS.Range("K4:O" & lookupLR).Copy SummaryCodeWS.Range("B" & summaryLR).Offset(2, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: If the last row `lookupLR` is not what you expect, well then there's your problem.

Comment: So even though it's defined as lookupLR = MasterCodeWS.Range("K10000").End(xlUp).Row, it could still not pick up the changing results that need to be transcribed to the summary ws?

Comment: I'm still learning all this so is there a route or step(s) I can take to resolve this?

Comment: Try moving `lookupLR = MasterCodeWS.Range("K10000").End(xlUp).Row` inside the `For Each` loop.

Comment: omygoodness it worked! Thank you for your time and patience in explaining all of this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want to find the last row dynamically. Move

```
lookupLR = LookupWS.Range("K10000").End(xlUp).Row
```

to immediately before

```
arr = LookupWS.Range("K4:O" & lookupLR).Value
```

Side note, if you don't want to hard-code the `10000` (probably a good idea to avoid this), then use:

```
With LookupWS
   lookupLR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

Comment: I forget I should post HOW i resolved it with your recommendation but that's exactly where I placed it. And thank you for the additional suggestion. I updated it and re-ran and looks great!